Can I simplify multiple inequality cases into a single absolute inequality?
I'm not an expert and I haven't dealt with these kinds of inequalities for a while, so I'm hoping someone can explain if my thinking process is reliable and will suffice to prove the results I'm looking for.
I start with the expression
$$
| |x+y|-|x|-b |,
$$ and I'd like to know if this is less than or equal to
$$
| |y| - b|.
$$
My approach is

first, take the positive case: then we have that $|x+y| - |x| - b \leq |y| - b$.
For the negative case, we have that $|x| - |x+y| +b \geq b - |y|$.
So, does this then mean that
$$
b - |y| \leq | |x+y| - |x| - b| \leq |y| - b
$$ which in turn implies, after combining the cases, that
$$
| |x+y| - |x| - b| \leq | |y| - b|\;?
$$

I sure hope so! Thanks in advance for answering.

Up to this point it is ok, but you have many more cases to studiy to come up with x, y

$b-|y| \le |y|-b$ can't be univerally true.  Just take $b > |y|$.  You have that if $|x+y|-|x| -b >0$ then $0 < |x+y|-|x|-b \le |y| - b$ so $|y|- b>0$. But I don't think the negative case works.  You have $0 < -(|x+y|-|x|-b)=|x|-|x+y|+b$ and $ |x|-|x+y|+b\ge b-|y|$ but was don't know whether $b-|y|$ is positive or negative.  It could be either.

Take $y=-27; x=25$ and $b=30$ then $||x+y|-|x|-b|=||-2|-|25|-30|=|2-25-30|=|-53|=53$ and $||y|-b|=|27-30|=|-3| = 3$ and $||x+y|-|x|-b| > ||y|-b|$.

Your positive case works.  If $|x+y|-|x| - b \ge 0$ then $0 \le ||x+y|-|x|-b|| = |x+y|-|x|-b \le |y| -b$.  As $|y|-b\ge 0$ then $||y|-b| = |y|-b$ and your result is. $||x+y|-|x|-b||\le |y|-b$.
But you negative case does not work.  If $|x+y|-|x| - b < 0$ then $0 \le  ||x+y|-|x|-b|| = |x|-|x+y| + b$ and $|x|-|x+y| + b \ge b-|y|$.  But as that is a $\ge$ rather than a $\le$ sign we don't know whether $b-|y|$ is positive or negative.  If $b \ge |y|$ we will have $||x+y|-|x|-b|| \ge ||y|-b|$ (which is the opposite of what you were expecting) but if $b < |y|$ (and $b > |x+y|- |x|$) then we can't conclude anything.
....
Concluding $b-|y| \le something \le |y|-b$ should have clued you into potential errors as we have no way of knowing whether $b\ge |y|$ or $|y| > b$.
Indeed we we do always have
$|x+y| - |x| -b \le |y| -b$.  Then if $|y|\ge b$ we have $-(|y|-b) \le |x+y| - |x| -b \le |y| -b$ so $||x+y|-|x|-b| \le ||y|-b|$.
BUT if $|y|< b$ then we have $|x+y| - |x| -b \le |y| -b < 0$ so
$|x+y| - |x|-b| < |y|-b < 0 < -(|x+y| - |x|-b)$ and there for $||y|-b| < ||x+y|-|x|-b|$.
ANd that's our result.  Our "positive" and "negative" test shouldn't have been on |x+y| -|x|-b$ but on $|y|-b$.
Our result is:
Case 1:  $|y|\ge b \implies ||x+y|-|x|-b|\le ||y|-b|$
Case 2:  $|y| < b\implies ||x+y|-|x|-b| > ||y|-b|$
....
We do always have $|x+y| - |x| - b \le |y| -b$ and we always have $b-|y| \le |x| -|x+y| +b$  but which of those positive or negative will determine how to compare the absolute values.

Thank you for your response. Since posting this question I've explored how to prove statements and case-by-case processes like yours.

Let's phrase the question this way: we want to know when
$\lvert \lvert x+y\rvert - \lvert x\rvert -b\rvert$
is less than or equal to $\lvert \lvert y\rvert - b\rvert$.
You are hoping the answer is "always".
Equivalently, we want to know when
$$\left(\lvert \lvert y\rvert - b\rvert\right)
 - \left(\lvert \lvert x+y\rvert - \lvert x\rvert -b\rvert\right) \geq 0. \tag1$$
(The parentheses are technically redundant in this formula,
but I added them because I was having trouble keeping count of the absolute value bars.)
The problem with "positive" and "negative" cases is that we have several subexpressions here and it is possible that some are positive while others are negative. That can make for a lot of cases.
Another thing that sometimes helps is to view the absolute value as a way to evaluate a "distance" between numbers on the number line.
In particular, the "distance" between $u$ and $v$ is $\lvert u - v\rvert$.
Now let's just consider the expression $\lvert x+y\rvert - \lvert x\rvert$
that appears in the formula. We can rewrite this as
$$ \lvert x - (-y)\rvert - \lvert x - 0\rvert, $$
which says that we take the distance between $x$ and $-y$ and subtract from this the distance between $x$ and $0$.
We can separate the evaluation of this particular expression into three cases if we suppose that "$u$ is between $v$ and $w$" means that either
$v \leq u \leq w$ or $w \leq u \leq v$, or in other words, we use "between" in a way that does not mean "strictly between".
Then we must be able to say for at least one of the numbers $x$, $-y$, and $0$ that it is between the other two. Choose which number you want to be between the others, and that defines a case. If two or more of the numbers are equal, more than one of these cases will apply, but that just means that the logic below will find the same answer in multiple ways.
First case
Let $0$ be between $x$ and $-y$. Then
$\lvert x - (-y)\rvert = \lvert x - 0\rvert + \lvert  0 - (-y)\rvert$
(because to get from $x$ to $-y$ you must go from $x$ to $0$ and then from $0$ to $-y$)
and therefore
$\lvert x - (-y)\rvert - \lvert x - 0\rvert = \lvert  0 - (-y)\rvert = \lvert y\rvert$.
In this case we can evaluate the left side of Inequality $(1)$ as follows:
$$\left(\lvert \lvert y\rvert - b\rvert\right)
 - \left(\lvert \lvert x+y\rvert - \lvert x\rvert - b\rvert\right)
= \left(\lvert \lvert y\rvert - b\rvert\right)
   - \left(\lvert \lvert y\rvert - b\rvert\right)
= 0. $$
So the inequality is always true in this case.
Another way to describe this case is: $x$ and $y$ have the same sign.
Second case
Let $-y$ be between $x$ and $0$.  Then
$\lvert x - 0\rvert = \lvert  x - (-y)\rvert + \lvert -y - 0\rvert$
and therefore
$\lvert x - (-y)\rvert - \lvert x - 0\rvert 
= -\lvert  0 - -y - 0\rvert = - \lvert y\rvert$.
In this case we can evaluate the left side of Inequality $(1)$ as follows:
\begin{align}
\left(\lvert \lvert y\rvert - b\rvert\right)
 - \left(\lvert \lvert x+y\rvert - \lvert x\rvert - b\rvert\right)
&= \left(\lvert \lvert y\rvert - b\rvert\right)
  - \left(\lvert -\lvert y\rvert - b\rvert\right) \\
&= \left(\lvert \lvert y\rvert - b\rvert\right)
  - \left(\lvert \lvert y\rvert - (-b)\rvert\right).
\end{align}
Obviously, if either $y$ or $b$ is zero, this expression is equal to $0$.
But otherwise, if $b < 0$ then $\lvert \lvert y\rvert$ is farther from $b$
than from $-b$ and the overall value is positive;
but if $b > 0$ then $\lvert \lvert y\rvert$ is farther from $-b$
than from $b$ and the overall value is negative.
So the case where $x$ and $y$ have opposite signs, $\lvert x\rvert \geq \lvert y\rvert$, and $b > 0$ is a case where Inequality $(1)$ is false.
Third case
Let $x$ be between $0$ and $-y$. Then
$\lvert 0 - (-y)\rvert = \lvert 0 - x\rvert + \lvert  x - (-y)\rvert$
and therefore
$\lvert x - (-y)\rvert - \lvert x - 0\rvert 
= \lvert  0 - (-y)\rvert - 2\lvert x - 0\rvert = \lvert y\rvert - 2\lvert x\rvert$;
also, $\lvert x\rvert \leq \lvert y\rvert$.
In this case we can evaluate the left side of Inequality $(1)$ as follows:
\begin{align}
\left(\lvert \lvert y\rvert - b\rvert\right)
 - \left(\lvert \lvert x+y\rvert - \lvert x\rvert - b\rvert\right)
&= \left(\lvert \lvert y\rvert - b\rvert\right)
  - \left(\lvert\lvert y\rvert - 2\lvert x\rvert - b\rvert\right) \\
&= \left(\lvert \lvert y\rvert - b\rvert\right)
  - \lvert (\lvert y\rvert - b) - 2\lvert x\rvert\rvert.
\end{align}
In the case where $b \leq 0$, $\lvert y\rvert - b \geq \lvert y\rvert$ and therefore
$$ \lvert (\lvert y\rvert - b) - 2\lvert x\rvert\rvert
\leq \lvert y\rvert \leq \lvert \lvert y\rvert - b\rvert,$$
and therefore Inequality $(1)$ is true.
The other possibility is that $b > 0$. In that case, as long as
$\lvert x\rvert \leq \lvert y\rvert - b$,
we have $0 \leq 2\lvert x\rvert \leq 2(\lvert y\rvert - b)$,
therefore
$-(\lvert y\rvert - b) \leq (\lvert y\rvert - b) - 2\lvert x\rvert
\leq \lvert y\rvert - b$,
therefore
$\left(\lvert \lvert y\rvert - b\rvert\right)
  - \lvert (\lvert y\rvert - b) - 2\lvert x\rvert\rvert \geq 0$,
therefore Inequality $(1)$ is true.
But if $\lvert y\rvert - b < \lvert x\rvert  < \lvert y\rvert$
then Inequality $(1)$ is false.
Conclusion
We have found that Inequality $(1)$ is false in certain sub-cases of the second and third case above.
These sub-cases combine as follows:
If $b > 0$, if $x$ and $y$ have opposite signs (one strictly positive and the other strictly negative), and if $\lvert x\rvert > \lvert y\rvert - b$,
then Inequality $(1)$ is false.
Otherwise Inequality $(1)$ is true.
We now know that Inequality $(1)$ is not always true, and we have a relatively concise description of when it is not true.
Here is a link to the Wolfram Alpha plots of the left-hand side of the inequality for the case $b = \frac12$.
Below is the 3D plot.

Below is the contour plot.

Below is the contour plot, modified to show where the inequality is true and where it is false.

